# Dangling duplicate: "Tools to visualize relationships between object classes"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Background: I was looking for help with generating a UML diagram from a set of Java source files, directly within eclipse. Using the search string "[eclipse] [uml] [java] [reverse-engineering]" from within Stack Overflow's *Search Q&A* produced the following page in the #2 spot by "Newest" (asked in 2013, it's pretty old for a question about programming tools):

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/17176852/4983400

This question was closed as a duplicate. There are no answers. The close notice references the question [Good free UML tool for Java/Eclipse? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse), but that question seems to have been deleted. The 12 answers noted in the close notice are therefore inaccessible.

This leaves the original question unanswered and unanswerable (other than via comments), and so doesn't serve any purpose in the repository. The basic question is still of interest, ignoring the reference to the eclipse version number.

Suggestions:

1. Re-home it. Reopen the question, then close it again as a duplicate to a newer question. The following is a start, but there might be something more recent / relevant:

   [Eclipse Plugin for creating large java class diagrams from existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173724/eclipse-plugin-for-creating-large-java-class-diagrams-from-existing-code)
2. Bring relevant answers from the linked (deleted) question into the original question and reopen it (closing it again immediately if deemed off-topic as a 'tools' request).
3. Delete the original question altogether.

*Research done: I've searched Meta SO for an exact match (using double quotes) of the title of the original question, and nothing turned up.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question referenced here was a tool request, and those are off topic, it now got deleted by 3 members of the community.

I don't think we have any particular need to keep that tool request on the site.

Answer (score 2):

While it is unfortunate that the original question is not available to you, your question could be closed for being off-topic as well. As per the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), tool recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

> 4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Would my question (first sentence) actually be off-topic, though? The [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) includes this at item #4: "Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Its link leads to Shog9's answer, which concludes (in part), "So just ask how you should do what you want to do, and leave the library recommendations - if any - to the answerers." Would asking about generating *class diagrams* help? More generally - is it on-topic at SO to ask about the *usage* of tools (eclipse, in this case, though answers would likely mention plug-ins)?

Comment: @Lawrence if you are facing *concrete problems* while using a tool during software development, yes: [*if your question generally covers software tools commonly used by programmers and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ok, thanks! I climbed eclipse's learning curve when I first encountered it years ago. After some time away from programming regularly, eclipse is still quite familiar. But I've found that it has grown into some kind of marketplace that promises wonders - if only I knew the password :) . Time to climb the new learning curve.